# Moving register value to an array

Tags: assembly, embedded, msp430, texas-instruments

I am using the hardware multiplier in the MSP430 to multiply a constant (5) to each element of an array that I have initialized as arrX:   .int   8, 16, 32
I am wanting to write the product stored in R7 after each iteration to another array named arrY so when it finishes I will have arrY = 40, 80, 160
I am struggling to find the proper documentation that explains how to add register values to an array.

Comment: Look at compiler output: https://godbolt.org/z/1xTdeddcb.  You're not adding, you're just assigning aka storing.  Arrays in static storage are fixed size; you can't grow them if that's what you mean.  (But you can reserve as much space as you'll ever need, and keep track of how much is currently in use.)  Out of the things that are possible in asm, it's not clear what you actually want, so not easy to answer this.

Comment: I basically want to move a register value into a fixed 3 element array. The loop will run three times, therefore filling the array up with the products.

Comment: You can use indirect or indexed addressing.